# Scala Invoking Multiple futures - Consuming Queue when available

Tags: scala, asynchronous, functional-programming, future, scala-collections

I have a use case where I will make a call to an API which will return a list of ID's that I need to make a second API call.I am trying to use Scala Futures here, but seems stuck.

I have a scaled down example where i will add repose of first API to inpQueue and then iterate the inpQueue for making second APi call.
I need to start making the second API call as soon as data is available in the inpQueue. I tried to use Stream.continually(inpQueue), but it seems not working.

```scala
object DependentFutures {

  val datasets: immutable.Seq[(Int, String)] = 
Seq((1,"2X6barD"), (2,"3d9vCgW"), (3,"2M02Xz0"), (4,"2XOu2uL"), (5,"2AfBWF0")).toList


  var inpQueue  =  new ArrayBlockingQueue[Future[ (Int, String)]](1000)

  def addToQueue(params: (Int, String))(implicit ec: ExecutionContext):Future[ (Int, String)] = Future {
    val d = Future {(params._1 + 1, params._2)}
    inpQueue.put(d)

    println(new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())+" -> "+params._1 )
    (params._1+1, params._2)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val executor: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
    implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutorService = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executor)



    val q1 = Future.traverse(datasets)(addToQueue).andThen {
      case result =>
        println("* processing is over, shutting down the executor")
        executionContext.shutdown()
    }

    val x = Future.sequence(in)
    Await.result(inpQueue, Duration(10, "seconds")))(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an intermediate queue? Why not just `Future.traverse`?

Comment: What are the symptoms that it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the queue, you should poll from it in some place in some loop.
If you have `Future`s in the queue - you can processing by foreach function.

```
  def process(params: (Int, String)): Unit = ???
  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    {
      implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutorService = 
        ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
      Future.traverse(datasets)(addToQueue).andThen {
        case result =>
          println("* processing is over, shutting down the executor")
          executionContext.shutdown()
      }
    }
    
    implicit val ec: ExecutionContext  = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))
    while (true) {
      val currentResultFuture = inpQueue.poll(Long.MaxValue, SECONDS)
      currentResultFuture.foreach(process)
    }
  }
```